# Python: How to get some characters in the menu bar underlined?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, menu, underline

I built with Python a tkinter menu and I would like to underline in it some characters. I used the command "underline" in some lines, but strangely the characters are not appearing as underlined.
What should I do that "underline" finally works and starts to underline a given index? Did I have something forgotten?

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Menu


class Window():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__window = Tk()
        self.__set_window()
        self.__set_menu()


    def __set_window(self):
        self.__window.geometry("700x500")
        self.__window.minsize(500, 200)
        self.__window.title("Some Text")
        self.__window.iconbitmap("MyIcon")

    def start_window(self):
        self.__window.mainloop()

    def __set_menu(self):
        self.__menubar = Menu(self.__window)
        self.__file= Menu(self.__menubar, tearoff=0)


        self.__file.add_command(label = "Exit", underline=1, accelerator="Strg + C")
        self.__menubar.add_cascade(label="File", underline=0, menu=self.__datei)

        self.__menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", underline=1)


        self.__menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", underline=0)
        self.__window["menu"] = self.__menubar
```

Comment: To anyone else reading this: the answer appeared a comment.  Alan is using Win10 and underlines do not appear until one hits Alt.

Answer (score 2):

Underlines in tkinter menus are definitely determined by the underline command.  In your example, the 'F' in file, and the 'x' in Exit are both underlined.  After fixing the typo below, (and adding code to call the class) I had the underlines show up correctly.

from:

```
self.__menubar.add_cascade(label="File", underline=0, menu=self.__datei)
```

to:

```
self.__menubar.add_cascade(label="File", underline=0, menu=self.__file)
```

Do you still have the error when you run the code snippet as opposed to your complete file?

Comment: I fixed it but unfortunately the error is still there. Nothing is going to be underlined. :(

Comment: Are you running the code snippet or your original code?  I added 'self.__window.mainloop()' to the end of the init in your snippet, then called the class at the end of the file, and I get the underlines showing up on my screen.  I'm on Ubuntu, so it could be a platform-specific thing.

Comment: I'm running the fixed code I've posted here on Windows 10 and no character isn't underlined. If this is a platform-specific thing so I think I have got the final answer for my problem. Thank you TT.R for your help. :)

Comment: On Win10 (and maybe other versions), the underlines do not appear until you hit Alt.

Comment: Is there any way get around pressing Alt? Is there a way to show them by default?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10/11, there is a setting under Accessibility that will enable or disable automatic underlining of access keys. Within Settings, you can search for "underline access keys" and it will take you right to the toggle button.